# How does syntax coloring work

Tags: rascal

What is the right way of doing syntax coloring in a grammar? I believe it was like this:

```
syntax MappingName = @category="Constant" mappingname: Id mapping;
```

But it doesn't work for me. The file is just black text without parse errors (and it is open in the IMP editor, and I saw it create a parser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inspiration, you can always look at the [Rascal grammar](https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/rascal/syntax/Rascal.rsc). Where you can see that your syntax and category name seem correct.

Try what happens if you have no name for the production?

```
syntax MappingName = @category="Constant" Id mapping;
```

Comment: As I found out, I had still a parse error at the end of the file. Eclipse didn't show an error though, so I was puzzled. Parsing on the commandline showed the error.

Comment: also checkout the categories contribution: [IDE::Contribution::categories](https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal-eclipse/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/eclipse/library/util/IDE.rsc#L34) where you can add new categories and their colouring. [Or completely change the colors to for example the Solarized scheme](https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal-eclipse/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/eclipse/library/util/SyntaxHighlightingTemplates.rsc)